# How to set the state of random in php to be the same for an hour

Tags: php, random

I know this would be possible in python, and could most likely pull it off, but I can't seem to find much in PHP to do with random states

I would like a random item to be pulled out of a list, and running the code again within the hour will still return the same item

I've got the date to the nearest hour, and the code to get a random value from the list, I just need the bit linking the two

```
$hour = date('mdYh', time());
$url = $website."/".$lines[rand(1, count($lines)-1)];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: PHP scripts are executed from scratch every time a page is loaded. They are not long lived like a Python script, which can just keep running forever. The contents of any variables are lost when the script finishes. You would have to store the result of your random function in a file, database, or cache, along with what time it expires.

Comment: you can use [srand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) to set the seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the random number generator, then

```
srand(mktime(null, 1, 1));
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

I'm using mktime() to make a number that increases once per hour. Then, I use that number to seed php's random number generator. array_rand() uses the RNG, and so it will pick the same entry for the hour.

But...php's RNG is global across the entire program, and so any other random numbers needed in other parts of the code will be very predictable(they too, will be the same for the hour). Beware.

Also, I haven't thought about how this will behave around daylight savings time.

Comment: Thanks, that should work fine I think :)  Just checking, when you say entire program, you mean all the code on that page and not the whole website right?

Comment: @peter Just the page.